# Accepting a char in a function that wants a string-literal.

Tags: c, string, char, string-literals

So I think I messed up. I created a function in my program that accepts a string literal for a place holder.

```
foo("c");


char foo(char *bar){
    //stuff
}
```

So i went off to work on another part of the program and when I came back to this part of the problem, I need a single char from a 2d char array to go in that place. I wrote the foo function in such a way that It has to be a string. I've tried everything to make it work. Please Help...

Comment: wouldn't *bar inside of foo give you the single character 'c'?

Comment: `foo( (char[]){ x, '\0' } );`  , where `x` is the other char you want to put in

Comment: BTW your function should accept `char const *bar` instead of `char *bar`, since it does not modify the string

Comment: @bruceg for the program its kind of the point. I program is a boggle type game where its trying to see all possible words starting from a point on the grid, that point being the string that needs to fit in the space of foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, I believe you want to convert a char from a 2d char array to a string to pass to the `foo` function.

**Solution**

```
char arr[2][2] = {{'0', '1'},
                  {'2', '3'}};
char c = arr[0][0]; // grab a char from the 2d array
char str[2] = "\0"; // gives {'\0', '\0'}
str[0] = c;         // fill in the first character
foo(str);
```

Comment: yes awesome thank you, any insight on how I can avoid this in the future? also char[2] is written like java. it would be char str[2];

Comment: You missed `char[2] str` . That code could be simplified to `char str[2] = { arr[0][0] };`

Comment: Wow, that's terrible! Fixed